# how do you withdraw statistics from website using ping option in Terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, ping

Simple question how do you ping using terminal for example Google and get back the statistics of it? I mean packets transmitted packets lost ttl etc. because I tried different options using ping --help but typing ping www.google.com the list in Terminal just keeps roll down icmp_req=1 icmp_req=2 icmp_req=3 and 4,5,6,7 and so on... and looks like never to stop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also tell ping the number of pings to send, or 'count.'

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

> PING www.google.com (74.125.228.49) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes
>   from iad23s06-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.228.49): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50
>   time=34.0 ms 64 bytes from iad23s06-in-f17.1e100.net (74.125.228.49):
>   icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=38.8 ms 64 bytes from iad23s06-in-f17.1e100.net
>   (74.125.228.49): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=38.8 ms
>
> --- www.google.com ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev =
>   34.053/37.272/38.897/2.287 ms

Comment: yes! that works too, thanx.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is hit Ctrl-C in the terminal, and it will stop. Then it will display the results you're looking for.

```
PING google.com (74.125.228.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from iad23s07-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.228.72): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=40.2 ms
64 bytes from iad23s07-in-f8.1e100.net (74.125.228.72): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=42.7 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.247/41.505/42.764/1.274 ms
```

Comment: hah indeed! thanx man a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!